# Eclipse: I can run a program but I couldn't debug it

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, makefile

I have downloaded the well-known linuxptp source code (C language) from: 
git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/linuxptp/code linuxptp

It is a makeFile project which I could successfully run from command line, however the problem appears when I try to import it to Eclipse:
File > New > Makefile project with existing code

I can successfully build it and run it but I couldn't debug or force it to stop at a break point. I keep getting the message (No source available for "main() at 0x401eb5").

I tried to reinstall Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers from the official website but it didn't work.

I think it is useful to mention that: 
 - the source code I'm using contains different files with main() function
 - Eclipse debugger runs successfully on projects created on Eclipse from scratches

Any ideas?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should create some debugging launch configurations for your different executables in the project.

Also be sure that the Makefiles include -g option when compiling to produce the required debugging information.

Edit:

Add this lines to your Makefiles:

```
CFLAGS += -g
CXXFLAGS += -g
```

Comment: I've created a debugging configuration for the executable I need to debug/run. But I didn't get clearly what do you mean by -g in the Makefile. 
This is a relevant part of the Makefile:
KBUILD_OUTPUT = ||
DEBUG =  ||
CC = $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc ||
VER     = -DVER=$(version) ||
CFLAGS = -Wall $(VER) $(incdefs) $(DEBUG) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS) ... should I just assign the value -g to the DEBUG variable? (NOTE: || means a newline in the Makefile because I couldn't do newlines in this comment)